# How to enable the light sensor with ADB while the screen is off?

Tags: sensors

how to enable the light sensor with ADB while the screen is off?
I want to check the values of /sys/class/sensors/light_sensor/lux, but it changes only when the screen is on.

What I have tried, but did not work:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39215746/21702461
   There is no file called "enable" in that directory.
2. Tried to find a light sensor service, while the screen is on. But it seems there is none.

`dumpsys activity services | grep light`

`service list | grep light`

My phone:
Samsung Galaxy S4 with LineageOS and root enabled.